# Help with creating a filter for a data grid!

Tags: c#

I want to create a filter to filter text in a datagrid as i type in a text box. I have two text boxes, one to filter in text that i type and one to filter out text that i type. I want the data grid to update as i type into either one of the textboxes. Here is some of my code:

```
    private void txtFilterIn_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = dgPortStatus.DataContext as DataView;
        if (dv != null)
        {
            if (dv.Table.TableName.ToUpper() == "PORTSTATUS")
            {
                FilterDataGrid(txtFilterIn.Text, txtFilterOut.Text, _dicPortStatus[cmbGroups.SelectedItem.ToString()]);
            }
        }

        List<QuarantineView> qvList = dgPortStatus.DataContext as List<QuarantineView>;
        if (qvList != null)
        {
            //Filter on quarantine manager
            FilterQuarantineViewList(qvList);
        }
    }

    private void btnFilterInClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtFilterIn.Clear();
    }

    private void txtFilterOut_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = dgPortStatus.DataContext as DataView;
        if (dv != null)
        {
            if (dv.Table.TableName.ToUpper() == "PORTSTATUS")
            {
                FilterDataGrid(txtFilterIn.Text, txtFilterOut.Text, _dicPortStatus[cmbGroups.SelectedItem.ToString()]);
            }
        }

        List<QuarantineView> qvList = dgPortStatus.DataContext as List<QuarantineView>;
        if (qvList != null)
        {
            //Filter on Quarantine Manager
            FilterQuarantineViewList(qvList);
        }
    }

    private void btnFilterOutClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtFilterOut.Clear();
    }
```

And this method is where my filter needs to go:

```
private void FilterQuarantineViewList(List<QuarantineView> qvList)
{


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            r.Visible = false;
            foreach (DataGridViewCell c in r.Cells)
                if (c.Value.ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text))
                {
                    r.Visible = true;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If i do it like that then this statement will not work:
List<QuarantineView> qvList = dgPortStatus.DataContext as List<QuarantineView>;
        if (qvList != null)
        {
            //Filter on quarantine manager
            FilterQuarantineViewList(qvList);